# Can we get subgroup on the basis of multiple currencies?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I have a mongo document of orderData. And i want to apply some aggregation on it. I have projects and on the basis of projects i want to group my order information.

But problem is that my orders will be in two currencies against one customer and i want to show both currencies total in my UI.

```
[{
        "orderNumber": "abc#1",
        "project": "project1",
        "cashCollection": {
            "iso": "USD",
            "total": 100
        }
    },
    {
        "orderNumber": "abc#2",
        "project": "project1",
        "cashCollection": {
            "iso": "EUR",
            "total": 100
        }
    },
    {
        "orderNumber": "abc#3",
        "project": "project1",
        "cashCollection": {
            "iso": "USD",
            "total": 100
        }
    }
]
```

And i want response like that.

```
{
    "project": "project1",
    "totalCashCollection": [{
            "iso": "USD",
            "total": 200
        },
        {
            "iso": "AUD",
            "total": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to fetch this result via mongo template. And i am stuck on it . can any body help???

Comment: use $group on project field in aggregate pipeline using $push on cashCollection

Comment: @sushantmehta really appreciated. it worked. Thank you so much